# Format a date and time string

Tags: r, date, formatting

I need to convert a string such as:

```
"19480804 14:00"
```

to a date formatted as below:

```
"Aug 4th, 1948 2 PM"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All information: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

You have to change string into date format, example:

```
date <-("19480804 14:00")
x <- strptime(date,"%Y%m%d %H:%M")
```

output:

```
[1] "1948-08-04 14:00:00 CEST"
```

additionaly:

```
format(x, format="%b %d, %Y %I %p")
```

and output:

```
"Aug 04, 1948 02 PM"
```